# Looking for sitecore WF comment pipeline

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, workflow

I am looking to see if there a way to pre-fill the fields in the comment template, just wondering if there is a pipeline to do this?

Comment: Could you use a custom Comment template and set the standard values for the comment?

Comment: @Richard Seal in this case I want the values entered in the preview state to Persist in the stage and prod comment box.

Comment: What's the point in a comment box if it's filled with default content? Then it's just noise.

Comment: @MichaelWest in my case when we move from Draft to Preview, the comment box will  be empty, here the content author enters the comments, when we move from preview to staging.. it must pre-fill the values entered previously... that way incase there are any further comments to make we can just append them or atleast edit them... incase if the comment remains the same, we can just click OK...that way it saves time for the content authors.